# In how many ways can I write $0$ as a sum of $n\; 0s, 1s \;\text{and}\; -1s?$

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can I write $0$ as a sum of $n\; 0s, 1s \;\text{or}\; -1s?$  (Taking the order into account).
I suspect there is no closed formula to express the result, but I'd like someone to confirm it, or deny it.

Edit:
e.g., if $n=3$
$$\begin{aligned}0&=\;\;\;0+0+0,\\ 0&=\;\;\;1-1+0,\\ 0&=\;\;\;1+0-1,\\ 0&=\;\;\;0+1-1,\\ 0&=-1+1+0,\\ 0&=-1+0+1,\\ 0&=\;\;\;0-1+1.\end{aligned}$$
So for $n=3\;$ there are $7$ ways.

Comment: Set up a recurrence perhaps.

Comment: do you mean n each or a total of n?

Comment: Sorry I meant that in total, the number of 0's, 1's and -1's is n

Comment: @MJD Thsnks for pointing out that I'd missed the $n$. I've deleted the answer!

Comment: I'd start here: for each $n$, we can choose how many times $0$ occurs ,and how many times $1$ occurs. $-1$ then has to match $1$. So if $0$ is used $r$ times and $1$ is used $s$ times, $r=n-2s$.Then for each choice of $r$ and $s$ you've got a defined permutation problem, with $r, s$ and $s$ items..

Comment: For a proof by induction we might need two base cases (one for odd $n$ and one for even $n$): consider the ways to insert two new terms in the expression (either two $0's$, or a $1$ and a $-1$). It doesn't look nice though, because which possibilities are distinct depends on the existing terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$s(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{n-2k} \cdot \binom{2k}{k}$ The first term is the number of ways to arrange the zeroes, and then the second term arranges the parities. Now, we can simplify further:

$s(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \frac{2k!}{2k!} \cdot \frac{n!}{(n-2k)!(k!)(k!)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \frac{n!}{(n-2k)!(k!)(k!)}$

Edit: put a few values into the OIES and came across [trinomial coeffecients](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrinomialCoefficient.html). In particular, s(n) is the n-th [central trinomial coefficient](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralTrinomialCoefficient.html), which has several closed forms, which you can find in the second link.

Comment: This looks wrong to me. There are $k$ $1$'s, $k$ $(-1)$'s and $n-2k$ zeroes, so the denominator should be $(k!)^2(n-2k)!$.

Comment: Whoops yeah I forgot a term

Comment: Yes, I got the same formula. Do you think It can be simplified into a closed formula?

Comment: @LucioTanzini nothing immediately comes to mind without getting my hands dirty, but I’m thinking on it.

Comment: Update: found closed form.

Answer (score 0):

The number of $0s, 1s$ and $-1s$ possible for a particular $n$ can be seen by the number of solutions to:

$$2p+q=n| p,q \in \Bbb Z^+$$

This can be done in $\frac{n+1}{2}$ ways for odd $n$ and $\frac{n+2}{2}$ ways for even $n$

You'll just need to account for positioning after this.

Comment: Yes, but I'm afraid positioning is the main problem Indeed